# Reload URL specified using java program

Tags: java

To use my application,i need to relaod the XML page URL for every 5 to 10 sec,so please tell me how to reload or refresh the specified URL(Https://localhost:8080/java/dataformatureerfew5&6) for every 5 sec using java programming(without Refreshing it manually)

Comment: is it a swing program, how do you want to use java, that will allow people to suggest correctly

Comment: sorry its a applet AWT programming....(Vaadin framework)

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about what you want to achieve. It would be helpful if you can show some code too.

Comment: Thank you , i got it using To reload/refresh the URL, you can initiate a java HTTP request by using java.net.HttpUrlConnection. Comprehensive detail on this can be found here.http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Java [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) for scheduling. An easy and related example can be be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm).

To reload/refresh the URL, you can initiate a java HTTP request by using [java.net.HttpUrlConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). Comprehensive detail on this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2793153/945945).

Comment: can you please tell me the simple code to reload "eg:http://www.google.com/sdfdfde74743/"

Comment: Thank you very much I got using you adviceTo reload/refresh the URL, you can initiate a java HTTP request by using java.net.HttpUrlConnection. Comprehensive detail on this can be found here.

Comment: @user736260: I am glad it helped. If you think it solved your problem then kindly 'accept' this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class to schedule such (or any) task at a fixed rate (5-10 secs in your case).